# EncryptedSharedPreferences as credentials store

Tags: android, keystore, credentials, encrypted-shared-preference

Is it ok to store login credentials in EncryptedSharedPreferences or is it better to use something like the KeyStore.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to go for security, I would advise the later, the main reason being the [extraction prevention](https://developer.android.com/training/articles/keystore#ExtractionPrevention) steps that were taken when implementing the Keystore system

Comment: but both options would work